# When to specify function type in C?

Tags: c, function

I have just started learning C Programming and while trying to do a couple of example exercises, I found myself confused as to when is the best scenario to specify the function type.

I apologize in advance if my title is misleading.

One such example is getting the dollars (number of notes) where I am suppose to print out the results.
While I have it working, I am using `void` but while looking online, it seems that `int` function should be used instead?

I have 2 questions:

1. Initially I have my `printf` statement under `void`, in general coding, should such print statements be placed there or should it be in `main()`?
2. As mentioned above, using this case example of mine, is it a right/ wrong to use `void`?

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void dollars_calculation(int *input_amt, int dollars_value)
{
    int change_result = 0;

    change_result = (*input_amt / dollars_value); 
    printf("Number of %3d-dollars:\t%d pcs\n", dollars_value, change_result);

    if (change_result)
    {
      *input_amt = (*input_amt - (dollars_value * change_result));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int input_amt = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    int dollars_arr[3] = {100, 50, 10};


    printf("Input amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &input_amt);

    for (counter=0; counter<3; counter++)
        {
            // Check for the number of denomiations required.
            dollars_calculation(&input_amt, dollars_arr[counter]);
      }

}
```

Comment: `is it a right/ wrong to use void` - but where? The only `void` keyword you use is to specify the return type of `dollars_calculation` function.

Comment: Your program does not compille, you scanf for `input_amount` but then you're not using `input_amount` and it is not even declared. What is the program supposed to do? Please [edit] the question and clarify. That would make it easier for us to provide an answer.

Comment: Generally, C allows function to return a value either through the return value, or through one of the parameters passed as a pointer. The latter is actually the most common, since most APIs reserve the return value for error codes and similar.

Comment: @KamilCuk Sorry about that, first time using this platform and written in the code without doing a thorough check. I have updated the code. Basically I am trying to ask for my `dollars_calculation` function, in this case example of mine, is it right/ wrong to use void?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "function type" as you call it is actually the data type that you might want the function to return.

For example your `dollars_calculation` function could return an `int`, which is the result of your calculation, rather than using the pointer value to set an external variable.

Alternatively, you may be want a value returned that can be used to indicate success or failure of a function. This need not be a Boolean value, but could be an integer or even an enumerated type.

In general you want to write functions so that they are fully re-entrant - meaning that they can be called multiple times and their function will remain the same regardless of program state. A function that has a void return type and takes no parameters is usually an indication of a non-re-entrant function.

The use and location of `printf` statements depends on your program structure and what you intend your program to do. There's no right or wrong place to use them, but in some environments you may wish to locate them in one module (code file) for convenience e.g. the output is formatted or directed in a particular way.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have another question if you do not mind. Say if I do change my `dollars_calculation` to be an `int` type function, say if I want to incorporate a print statement that says "no. of <dollars value>-dollars : <number found>" for such statements, would you place it within the `dollars_calculation` function, or within the `main` function instead (within the for-loop)?

Comment: Personally, I'd place the `printf` statement in `main` because then I could have a second function, say euro_calculation that returns an `int` and use the same `printf` statement. Selection of which function to run could be governed by user input acted on by a `switch` statement. Structuring code is about ensuring as much re-use of code as possible